# TypeScript dynamic imports and exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I am trying to convert the following Node JS script to TypeScript:

```
const functions = {
    'auth/onCreate.js': true,
    'auth/onDelete.js': true,
    // ...
};

const camelcase = require('camelcase');

for (const file in functions) {
    // exports enabled functions only
    if (functions[file]) {
        const functionName = camelcase(file.slice(0, -3).split('/'));

        if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === functionName) {
            exports[functionName] = require(__dirname + '/' + file);

            if (process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === functionName) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how `auth/onCreate.js` content is exported for instance:

```
exports = module.exports =
    functions.auth.user().onCreate((userMetadata, context) => {
      // ...
    });
```

The main issue I have is with the following line:

```
exports[functionName] = require(__dirname + '/' + file);
```

I have tried to use a dynamic TypeScript import but I cannot find a way to re-export the definition based on the name that is in the `functionName` variable? Is it possible?